# Please explain me the role of seed in class Random in java.util

Tags: java, random, seed

Whenever we create an object of **`Random`** class in java. We either of the constructor

- Random()
- Random(long seed)

What is the purpose of `seed` here in the 2nd constructor and how can I use it to my benefit i.e. manipulate its use?

Comment: On an **advanced** note, these "random" things are actually _pseudo-random_. That is they appear random enough for normal use, but are actually reproducible (hence not truly random) - this is where the seed input comes in. For something truly random, you should look at environmental noise and things like that, but of course that would be an overkill for simple applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer above sums it up clearly. As per [java api docs from oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29), the first constructor

`Random()`

"Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor. "

The seed is probably a derivative of the current time, or the current time itself. That should be enough to be "very likely to be distinct from any other invocation". Which, in essence, is most likely what you need, most of the time.

**So why have another constructor that takes a seed?**

Simply put, if you want to generate the same set of random numbers over and over, you use the same seed on your Random constructor. This is useful when doing experiments on different control sets, and you don't want to bother creating your own table of random inputs, but still want the same set of random input on a different experiment/control set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, from you i got to know a lot more that i intended too before asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as truly random numbers in computing.  The available methods for getting a random number across all programming languages is nothing but an algorithm to simulate random numbers.

In some languages (C++, I know for sure), an unseeded random number generator will return the same series of numbers on every fresh execution of the program.

What is common is to seed the random number generator with the current time (which will be random enough for most purposes) so that the algorithm starts with a random number each time.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-random number generators maintain some set of state information, which is advanced through some recurrence relation to determine the next value of the state.  The output of a PRNG is some function of the state.  Java's `Random` class uses a Linear Congruential Generator.  LCG's work using the recurrence relationship U<sub>i+1</sub> = (A U<sub>i</sub> + C) % M for some constant integer values A, C, and M. Java's current implementation uses a 48-bit state but uses 32 bits or less of it on each iteration of the recurrence.

Based on this, you can see that if you start with the same state you will get the exact same sequence of values out of your PRNG.  This can be useful if you want to be able to reproduce exactly the same sequence of "randomness", for instance for debugging or for comparing two experiments head-to-head.

If you invoke the constructor without an argument, it picks a starting value for the state with a promise that different invocations are very likely to be distinct from each other.  If you supply a seed to the constructor, that seed's value is used to set the initial state.